# How do I use Form.ShowDialog?

Tags: c#

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeLink cl = new ChangeLink();
            // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
            if (cl.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox. 
               // cl.AcceptButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                this.label4.Text = cl.textBox1Text;
            }
            else
            {
                this.label4.Text = "Cancelled";
            }
            cl.Dispose();

        }
```

When I click the button, I see the new Form and the textBox1 in the new Form. And I can type in the textBox1 something, but I can't see anywhere an OK or CANCEL buttons. Should I add them manualy in the new Form designer? And how to use them then?

This is the code in my new Form what I wanted to do is to type something in the new Form textBox1 and pass the text in the textBox1 to Form1 label4.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    public partial class ChangeLink : Form
    {
        public ChangeLink()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        public string textBox1Text
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox1Text = textBox1.Text;
            }
            set
            {
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So where are the OK and CANCEL buttons of the Form.ShowDialog?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You will need to add them yourself, you can add the buttons to your `Form` and set their [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Property. This will return the DialogResult and close the Form without you having to wire up any code. Here is an example using a Method to return the Value of The TextBox on Form2(There are two Buttons on Form2 with their DialogResults set to Cancel and Ok respectivly).

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2 = new Form2();
        DialogResult dr = frm2.ShowDialog(this);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            frm2.Close();
        }
        else if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = frm2.getText();
            frm2.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string getText()
    {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Given that your only tag is C#, and you expect an OK and CANCEL button, it seems to me that you are actually looking for the MessageBox function.
Creating and disposing a Form just for the sake of showing a messagebox dialog is uncessary.

```
if (MessageBox.Show("boxtext", "boxcaption" MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK) 
{
// Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox. 
// cl.AcceptButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
this.label4.Text = cl.textBox1Text;
}else
{
    this.label4.Text = "Cancelled";
}
```

[MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a wrapper for the same-named WIN32 API Function:

```
int WINAPI MessageBox(
  _In_opt_  HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpText,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpCaption,
  _In_      UINT uType
);
```

Note: If you already have a window-handle / Form make sure to pass it as the first parameter to MessageBox.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult?view=net-5.0

provides the best way showing how "OK" & "Cancel" buttons are linked
You need to manually add 2 buttons eg., button1 & button2

```
    // Set the accept button of the form to button1.
      form1.AcceptButton = button1;
     // Set the cancel button of the form to button2.
       form1.CancelButton = button2;
```

Acceptbutton, button1 is deemed to be the OK button.
CancelButton, button2 is deemed to be the Cancel button.

Frankly, none of the answers explicitly mention this.
So, I had to pitch in with this answer.

Further more, you can see MSDN documentation,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

what you want is the inputbox of visualbasic namespace and yes you can use it in c#

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if you create an form from the basic form class you need to define a button that returns the `DialogResult` in the properties of the button.

Those are most useful in the `FileDialog` , `MessageBox` etc.. where the class is a MS defined form.