# InvalidOperationException when I attempt running another Form

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    private void preferencesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Run(new Preferences());
    }
    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Run(new Configuration());
    }
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Run(new Configuration());
    }
```

This is the code I use. When I open the program it throws an exception after one of the specified events occurs. The debugger provides additional information: "Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead." which is something I think is normal. Using ShowDialog() (see code below) won't actually fix the problem.

```
    private void preferencesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.ShowDialog();
    }
    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Configuration.ShowDialog();
    }
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Configuration.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Instead, there is an error where "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Form1.ShowDialog()'. Yeah, it happens because VS2015 thinks that I want to show a dialog that belongs to the form, while my objection is to open another form. It will also suggest simplifying member access...

This is the code in Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace y_cruncher_GUI_edition
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [MTAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I have three forms in the project (Form1, Configuration and Preferences). The program opens Form1, and when a specific button is pressed I want to show either Configuration or Preferences.

I hope I haven't done anything stupid like the previous time I asked a question (still a newbie in this). Any comment, help or vote is appreciated. :)

Comment: Please use a proper title. Don't force people to read the entire question to understand what you are asking

Comment: BTW the error is rather obvious - you are *already* running your application, what is the purpose of calling `Application.Run`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering that quickly. Second, I want to open another form. Third, sorry for the innovenience but I forgot to finish the title...

Comment: Also, VS doesn't *think* you are trying to show a dialog, it *know* you are trying to call a non-static method as it it were a static one. `ShowDialog` applies to instances, while you call it on the *class* itself, ie as a static method.

Comment: If you want to open a form, do as is shown in *any* tutorial. Create a new instance of the form with `var someForm=new WhatsMyForm();` and then call `Show();` or `ShowDialog()` on it, ie `someForm.Show();`

Comment: For example, check [the documentation for Form.ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) or [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444086/how-do-i-use-form-showdialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is show another form simply put the following code in the button's onClick() event.

`Preferences p1 = new Preferences();`
`p1.show();`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried it and it was successful! I kinda modified it but it works fine! :)

Comment: No problem anything u need m8.