# Let code wait till OK button is clicked on form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form and a class. The class at some point calls the form. At that point the user has to give some input, click OK and at that point the class has to continue.

At this point I have the following to call for the form, which is working, but the class continues and does not wait.

```
templateForm.Show();
```

How do I get the class to wait till the user has clicked OK?

Comment: You can subscribe to ```Click``` event of the OK button.

Comment: If you want your templateForm to be showed modally then you should call _templateForm.ShowDialog();_ (modally means that every interaction with other part of your user interface are suspended until you dismiss the templateForm via clicking any button with a DialogResult property set except DialogResult.None

Comment: You can use click event and call the new form on that click.

Comment: What about `templateForm.ShowDialog();`, this will result in your required behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every form has a `ShowDialog` method.

Just like a `Messagebox`, you can show the form and wait until the `DialogResult` is `OK`.

In your shown form, you need to make the button `OK` to be the default `OK` response when the form is shown in `ShowDialog`.

See [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444086/how-do-i-use-form-showdialog)
and [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=net-5.0)

After the user finish to insert his dialog, you can access the text inserted.

Another alternative, is to use the InputBox for text input only: [VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#Microsoft_VisualBasic_Interaction_InputBox_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: I changed it to this: ```if (templateForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)```. The form is now shown, but when I click OK nothing happens, the code in the if statement is not executed.

Comment: In your button properties, in the form, change the OK button properties->Property `DialogResult` to OK